# how many cell phone can I charge at the same time on the same circuit?

Tags: power-supply, current

I work at a courier company and we use a lot of cell phones, most are recharged over night. The current practice is to utilize cheap power bars which can handle 6 chargers/phones. Thinking of setting up to store and charge from 18-24 units using 3-4 power bars. Basing the current draw of 100ma per charger this would result in between 2 and 3 amps for the total circuit. Am I on the right track here? Is it better to turn off the phones while charging? My major concern is safety/fire risk and I do not want to overload the circuit. I will have to check what else is on the circuit that I plan to use. Do not want to trip any breakers and affect other equipment.

Comment: modern phones charge more at 1.5 A to 5 A than at 100 mA. The phone operating current is low compared to the charging current, which you can see by the fact that you can carry around a phone much longer than you need to charge it. However, what's a "power bar"? For me, that's something coated in cheap chocolate...

Comment: @MarcusMüller [note the words on the side](https://assets.change.org/photos/8/lj/si/IALJsiQRIPHAPms-800x450-noPad.jpg?1540539139) and also note that it attracted more than a little stir when it came out (most likely because of those words).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, this is what some places call a power bar   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93417/surge-protectionkinda-with-a-power-bar

Comment: oh, in that case: guitar fogie: you can attach more than 1 kW of power to that without problem. Your phones charge at less than 25 W each, even if they're big phones with high-current chargers. You'll be fine.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 100mA is at the line voltage (120V/240V)? Otherwise it seems a bit low. Please also clarify whether you are considering a mains power strip or a USB strip. Each bar/strip has a power/current rating, so quote the numbers and report back please. I think by then the answer is almost a given!

Comment: thanks for the comments. The charger is a small cube shape and the numbers on the side show input and output. The 100ma is the input so i take that as what the charger is drawing. A power bar is  just a strip of 6 plugs connected to 110v ac mains most have a built in circuit breaker. Capacity is in the range of 1800 watts/15 amps.

Comment: I thank you all for the input. I built the rack and advised my boss to check out what else is on the same circuit. Just in case. Until the next time, this is Guitar fogie signing off